# Finding $Var(S^2), E(S^4),$ and unbiased estimator for $\sigma^4$ from random, normal samp

Tags: self-study, estimation, unbiased-estimator

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be a random sample of size $n$ from the normal distribution $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and let $S^2$ be the sample variance. (a) Find $V(S^2)$ and derive $E(S^4)$. (b) find an unbiased estimator of $\sigma^4$.

My attempt:

(a) Since we are sampling from a normal distribution, $\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2}$~$\chi^2(n-1).$ Hence, $Var(S^2)=Var(\frac{\sigma^2}{n-1}\frac{n-1}{\sigma^2}S^2)=(\frac{\sigma^2}{n-1})^2Var(\frac{n-1}{\sigma^2}S^2))=(\frac{\sigma^2}{n-1})^2Var(\chi^2(n-1))=(\frac{\sigma^2}{n-1})^2 2(n-1)=\frac{2\sigma^4}{n-1}.$

Also, $E(S^2)=\frac{\sigma^2}{n-1}E(\chi^2(n-1)=\frac{\sigma^2}{n-1}(n-1)=\sigma^2$. Since $E(S^4)=E((S^2)^2)=Var(S^2)+(E(S^2))^2=\frac{2\sigma^4}{n-1}+\sigma^4=\frac{\sigma^4(n+1)}{n-1}$

(b) From part (a), we have $E(S^4)=\frac{\sigma^4(n+1)}{n-1}$, so $\sigma^4=\frac{n-1}{n+1}E(S^4)=E(\frac{n-1}{n+1}S^4).$ Hence, $\frac{n-1}{n+1}S^4=\frac{n-1}{n+1}(\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar{X})^2)^2=\frac{1}{(n+1)(n-1)}(\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar{X})^2)^2$ is an unbiased estimator of $\sigma^4$.

Does this look alright?

Comment: Duplicate of:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/962283/finding-vars2-es4-and-unbiased-estimator-for-sigma4-from-random-n